# How to block a certain type of urls on robots.txt or .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, robots.txt

Currently on my webshop, on the category pages with too many pages, the urls end by https://www.example.com?p=2 p=3...
I want to tell to the robots.txt to not index urls ending by p=Number. How do I do this? It's a prestashop website by the way.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line in your `robots.txt` file:

```
Disallow: /?p=*
```

So for example, this would stop URLs like `example.com/?p=2` from being indexed by the likes of Google. The `*` symbol stands for ALL. So anything after `p=` would be included.

Answer (score 0):

If p= pagination, you wouldn’t want to disallow those URLs as you’d still want them crawled.

If you don’t want them indexed in Google, add a noindex tag to them but don’t place anything on them to prevent crawling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; do you know how I can create a rule that creates a noindex tag for all the site?